DBeaver in Eclipse doesn't recognise SQL scripts
I am using Eclipse 2023-12 on Win 11 to work on DB with DBeaver and I can't execute any SQL line anymore. DBeaver doesn't seem to recognise queries as my whole script is grayed out and if I try to execute a query nothing happens.
I have DBeaver, StatET, Bash Editor and Git installed and I already tried to uninstall/reinstall Eclipse as a whole but it doesn't fix the problem. DBeaver works fine outside of Eclipse but I'd really want to keep working in a single IDE.
EDIT: After reinstalling everything again and creating a new SQL script this error poped up

An error has occurred. See error log for more details. org/eclipse/jface/text/rules/RuleBasedPartitionScanner

Then this is the error I get in the log
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/text/rules/RuleBasedPartitionScanner
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditorBase.reloadSyntaxRules(SQLEditorBase.java:845)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor.reloadSyntaxRules(SQLEditor.java:3444)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor.onDataSourceChange(SQLEditor.java:2952)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor.onDataSourceChange(SQLEditor.java:2947)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.UIExecutionQueue.executeInUI(UIExecutionQueue.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:132)
        ...
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.RuleBasedPartitionScanner cannot be found by org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql_1.0.128.202409011551
    ... 30 more


This seems to be caused by your outdated Eclipse 2023-12 which is two releases behind. Probably you are using the latest DBeaver version which expects the moved RuleBasedPartitionScanner class at the new location. In general, please make sure to ask question and report issue on the latest version only.

Thanks for your answer. I will try to downgrade my DBeaver version and see if it fixes my problem. I understand but I cannot use Eclipse's latest version because StatET is yet to be available on it.
